# Group Specific set of data by Day

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting, service

Need to get a certain subgroup of data per day (Separated by weekday)

For example

```
Select weekday,bla,blabla,blablabla from dbo.blabla
where bla = @StartDate
and bla <=@endDate
```

I need the output to be:

Monday bla blabla blablabla

Tuesday bla blabla blablabla

If someone could help me that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) with **DW**

Something like

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())
```

You can then try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        VAL FLOAT,
        DateVal DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, '01 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, '02 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, '03 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4, '08 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, '09 Jan 2010'

SELECT  DATENAME(DW,DateVal),
        SUM(VAL)
FROM    @Table
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW,DateVal)
```

Comment: I have a job that runs everyday to insert the values daily it inserts the dates into the table.

Here is all the data i need:

SELECT tat_dateofsub [Dateofsub],
tat_weekday [Weekday],
tat_model [Model],
tat_reciepts [Receipts],
tat_dispatches [Dispatch],
tat_onhand [On Hand],
tat_wip [WIP],
tat_AwTriage [Aw Triage],
tat_awParts [AW Parts],
tat_Technician [At Tech],
tat_scrapped [Scrapped],
tat_Buffer [Buffer] 
FROM report..tat
Need to display this in weekly format seperated by day.
Can i use this to do this?
GROUP BY DATENAME(DW,DateVal)